# Maven dependencies - version vs updates

Tags: maven, maven-dependency

[*mvnrepository*](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.codingwell/scala-guice_2.13/4.2.6) usually lists "version" and "updates" for each dependency.

1. If I'm publishing my own package, how do I specify the "updates" version
2. Which dependancy does Maven used when resolving transitive dependencies? So if my package depends on package A, which depends of package B with - version = 1.0 and updates = 1.1. Which version of B would I get?

Comment: So you define to be depending on package A (version?) which depends on package B (version 1.0.) So you will get version 1.0 of package B if you don't overwrite it in your package...So you define the dependencies in your pom file which is checked into your version control which means this will not change until you change your pom file...May be i misunderstand the question? If you like to update you need to change the version of package A (different version)..?

Comment: What "updates" are you talking about? Take http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.valdr/valdr-bean-validation/1.1.2 for example, where do you see "updates"?

Comment: @MarcelStör: jackson-databind is version 2.4.0, updates 2.7.1-1

Comment: @khmarbaise: That's true is A depends on version 1.0 on B. But say in Marcel's example - Valdr Bean depends on jackson-databind. If I include Valdr Bean, when will I get jackson-databind 2.4.0, and when will I get version 2.7.1-1?

Comment: @EugeneMi Is there any more feedback you need? If not I suggest you consider to accept the answer so that SO can mark this question as closed, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.

Answer (score 106):

You're asking what the meaning of the information in the "Updates" column of MVNRepository's "Compile Dependencies" table is.

[image]

It tells you whether there's an updated version of a particular dependency available and if so what the latest version is. If there's a check mark it means the library in question already uses the latest version of dependency X. You will always get the *declared* version of a dependency no matter what the *latest* version is.

Hence, if you use [`valdr-bean-validation` 1.1.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.valdr/valdr-bean-validation/1.1.2) (example above) you'll also get `jackson-databind` 2.4.0 as a transitive dependency (1st row above). 2.7.1-1 would be the latest available `jackson-databind` version.

Notes: I finally understand your question. It would have been helpful for you to give us a concrete example right from the start.

Comment: I noticed that in some cases the "Updates" version is actually older than the "Version" version. e.g. "Version: 2.5.0-b42   ; Updates: 2.4.0" . Confusing.

Comment: Yes, [here's](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server/2.27) an example of the "updates" column having a older version than the "version" column. I guess "updates" column version is the version that the original library needs. Another question is about the check mark. The above explanation isn't clear. Is the check mark present in cases where the "version column" is the latest version and the original library requires that version?

Comment: @andy-dufresne Re: "Version: 2.5.0-b42 ; Updates: 2.4.0": by Maven standards (i.e. the way it compares version numbers) 2.5.0-b42 is not a generally available release but one of the alpha, beta or RC types. That's why it considers 2.4.0 to be the latest generally available version. It may just not be smart enough in this respect; I guess that's subjective. The checkmark simply means that (again according to Maven's version algorithm) the latest generally available version is the one declared in the project POM -> project is using the latest.

Comment: If I want use update version of transitive dependency, How can I configure in POM.xml

Comment: Are there any (weak) guarantees that the `updates` revision doesn't introduce breaking changes? A colleague once suggested that such info meant there were no breaking changes, but I'm not convinced.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat not that I know of. If the whole world used SemVer it might in theory be possible to derive this information from the difference in version numbers. However, there are projects which claim/appear to use SemVer but still release breaking changes with minor releases. There's just a single guarantee: there are no guarantees :-/